# What value can a hash column in a mysql table take?

Tags: python, mysql, hash

I'm trying to insert new values into a table in a MySQL database. One of the columns in the table is NewContactHash. This is from the database schema for the column used when creating the table:

```
`NewContactHash` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci GENERATED ALWAYS AS
(md5(upper(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replac
e(concat(`name`,`address1`,substr(`postal_code`,1,5)),'
',''),'.',''),',',''),'/',''),'(',''),')',''),'-',''),'&',''),'\'',''),'"','')))) STORED NOT NULL
```

What type of value (or format) can I insert into this column to insert a record into the database? It will not take an empty value or a value not in the format specified.

Comment: This is a generated column. You can't insert into it, it automatically performs the calculation from other columns in the table.

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html